# POST data with double brackets missing bracket

Tags: php, post

When this monster is sent via POST

```
<input name="arrayname[index][string[name]]" value="321" />
```

this is what i get:

```
print_r($POST['arrayname']);
>> Array ( [index] => Array ( [string[name] => 321) )
```

Where is the secons bracket?

I can access it via:

```
echo $val['string[name'];
```

but thats just horrible.

**The structure of the name should be kept if possible.**

Its part of a large generic method and only in some cases theese names get generated. If its not possible to work with names like theese properly (it is but ugly like i mentioned above), i will have to change the whole form generating.

Comment: I guess you cannot nest arrays in HTML POST requests like this.

Comment: strange thing is that i can access it like mentioned above.

Comment: it is not nesting, it is using the string `string[name` as key.

Answer (score 3):

```
Incorrect : arrayname[index][string[name]]


Correct : arrayname[index][string][name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose:

- Let PHP convert your POST data to arrays using the square bracket syntax
- Parse POST data yourself from [raw post data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data)

You just cannot have both at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input name="arrayname[index][string][name]" value="321" />
```

Comment: yeah i ommited saying that the structure of the name should be kept if possible.

Comment: there is not a single reason to keep that structure. Especially because it contradicts with PHP syntax.

Comment: its part of a large generic method and only in some cases theese names get generated. if its not possible to work with names like theese properly (it is but ugly like i mentioned above), i will have to change the whole form generating.